# A program in C# to tell whether opened applications are in maximized mode or not

Tags: c#, windowstate

I would like to know whether any libraries are available in Windows OS which allows us to capture other applications window states

Answer (score 2):

Use PInvoke to call `GetWindowPlacement`.

See here for details:

http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/getwindowplacement.html

You can use `FindWindowEx` to find the handle to the window.

Answer (score 0):

[Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/) as a large set of libraries that can be linked against in .NET.

It should have everything you need to do what you want - and a lot more.